# Concatenating consecutive numbers to find primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

I'm working on a sample problem where I'm figuring out if you can make primes concatenating the numbers 1-5 in any order, just that they all be used.

I first tried to look at the combinations of the last digits of the number to see if I could show that no primes are possible. For example, I know that the number can't end in 2,4,or 5 because that number would clearly be composite. So to end the number in either 1 or 3, then these are the only possibilities for primes. I thought that maybe I look at modulus, such as $$x ≡ 3 \pmod{10}.$$ But from Dirichlet's theorem there are infinite primes of the form $10n + 3$, so I can't rule that out either.

This is my attempt to practice for a much larger problem, so if the example of $1-5$ doesn't work very well please let me know.

Comment: Well, any such number is divisible by $3$.

Comment: lulu is right. Such a number will be $1\cdot 10^i + 2\cdot 10^j + 3\cdot 10^k + 4\cdot 10^l + 5\cdot 10^m$ and taken modulo $3$ we have $10 \equiv 1$ so it becomes $1+2+3+4+5=15\equiv 0$. For other numbers of digits, there may be no obstacles, for example numbers $1423,2143,2341,4231$ are all prime.

Comment: See also [casting out nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines).

Comment: @user2661923 Hello, I've tried to see how casting out nines could show me whether a number is prime, but I can't find anything about how it relates to my problem.

Comment: The number will be a multiple of $~3~$ if and only if the sum of the digits is a multiple of $~3.$